# How to set drag n drop files in AjaxFileUpload to false?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

AjaxFileUpload allows drag and drop files feature by default, how can I turn it off?

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
        MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" 
        onuploadcomplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of AjaxFileUpload control, there is no property that lets you do that. But if you look at the source of the rendered page, you can see that the *drop zone* is decorated by a class called ``. So once the control gets loaded, you could do this client-side

JavaScript

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ajax__fileupload_dropzone")[0].style.display="none";
```

jQuery

```
$(".ajax__fileupload_dropzone").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .ajax__fileupload_dropzone {
        display:none;
    } 
    </style>
```

By this i was able to get it to hide the drop zone.

Comment: This made the control unusable for me.  No go.